# storing whole innerhtml design of a DIV to a variable

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am trying to fetch the whole `innerHtml` of a DIV to a PHP variable.

For this what I have done is to put the whole of the `innerHtml` into a Hidden field, and then call the Hidden field into php.

My code is:

```
<form method="post">
    <div class="container" id="content">
    <h1>Header1</h1>
    <p>this is the para</p>
    <textarea id="address" name="address"></textarea>
    </div>
    <input type="hidden" id="hidhtm" name="hidhtm"/>
</form>
```

In my JS file I have:

document.getElementById('hidhtm').value = document.getElementById('content').innerHTML;

In my PHP I have:

$test = $_POST['hidhtm'];
echo $test;

Can anyone please help me on this.

Comment: Is there a form somewhere in your page?

Comment: @j08691...yes am having a form...should I share the whole HTML?

Comment: where is the element called 'content'? What is the output you are expecting, and what are you getting?

Comment: i want the innerHtml of the DIV id Content

Comment: your question is worded poorly.  Its seems like a simple answer.  Do you just want to get the innter html of a div?  Easily done with JQUERY.  Explain more.

Comment: @StephenCarr..yes thats what I want can you help me with this

Comment: yes...i just want to get the inner html of a div into a hidden input box...

Comment: i think the issue is with storing in an hidden input because while trying to store it in a variable I got success! anyone please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wanted to do the same thing, and tried your method and it works.
In my test, the Javascript function which extracts the innerHMTL and places it in the hidden field of the form is called upon the user clicking a button which enabled the "submit" button (eg. acceptance of terms and conditions) but which does not actually submit the form.  Therefore the hidden field was populated before the form was submitted.  I haven't tried doing the same thing "onSubmit" but I suspect it might be too late to do so then.
I found that the material which could be inserted into the hidden field included all the values inserted by the user onto the form as well as things inserted by Javascript itself.  All this could be picked up from the $_POST variable for the hidden field. 
I needed to do this so that the PHP server could create a new form dynamically and send it back to the user.

Answer (score 0):

function add_question(){

    var count=document.getElementById("nofquest").value;

    var container = document.getElementById("container");
            // Clear previous contents of the container
            while (container.hasChildNodes()) 
            {
                container.removeChild(container.lastChild);
            }
            for (i=1;i

please find text boxes in center how to align